# How does Nginx server_name directive work with CNAME record

Tags: dns, nginx

**Scenario**

I have a website served by `nginx` listen at domain `myabc.domain.com`.

The `nginx` configuration is:

```
server {
  listen                      443 ssl;
  server_name                 myabc.domain.com`;
  root                        /home/ubuntu/portal;



  location / {

    # other directives
}
```

Then I add an A record in DNS server:

myabc.domain.com -> 123.123.123.123

It is working fine.

Then, I add a CNAME record to DNS server

myabc2.domain.com -> myabc.domain.com

I tried accessing the webpage from browser with myabc2.domain.com and it works!?

**Question**

I expect the `nginx` server_name to only permit access to this site whose `host` header is `myabc.domain.com`.

The `host` header is set automatically by browsers to be the one I typed in. (I assume)

So why doesn't `nginx` deny access to this request?

Comment: "I expect the nginx server_name to only permit access to this site whose host header is myabc.domain.com." Why do you expect that?

Comment: Thanks. I remember skimming through this directive sometime ago. I should have revised it before asking this question.

Apparently, my question describes a specific case when no server with matching `server_name`  is found, the request will be routed to the first server - which is the `myabc.domain.com` server in my setting.

Comment: I'll delete this question since it's not likely going to be helpful for others.

Comment: You can post what you found as answer. Somebody else might have the same expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Once again, `Assumption` is never a good thing. `Reading document` is the way to go.

Thanks @muru for pointing that out for me.

The answer is that:

My question describes a specific case when no server with matching `server_name` is found. In such situation, `nginx` will route the request to the first specified server listening on that port - which is the myabc.domain.com server in my setting.

Ref: [Nginx's document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)